# WooCommerce - Create multiple product tags via rest api endpoint

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I’m really confused here but I want to try create multiple terms via the woocommerce rest api, the example shows one term being added:

```
$data = [
    'name' => 'Leather Shoes'
];

$woocommerce->post('products/tags', $data);
```

> https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product-tag

When adding a term this way, the rest api requires me to set the array key as name. I thought maybe I just add multiple items like this:

```
$data = [
    'name' => 'Leather Shoes',
    'name' => 'tagtest',
    'name' => 'helloworld',
];
```

But because each item is using name as the key, it ends up only setting the last item:

```
$data = [
  'name' => 'Leather Shoes',
  'name' => 'Example',
  'name' => 'TagTest',
];

var_dump($data);

array (size=1)
  'name' => string 'TagTest' (length=7)
```

Then, tried setting different values other than name and got an error:

> Error: Missing parameter(s): name

**Question**
So I’m trying to figure out how I pass multiple terms/tags to the `$woocommerce->post('products/tags')` rest api endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside whether you're making the API request from and to the same site or not, I assume that the `$woocommerce` is an instance of [`Automattic\WooCommerce\Client`](https://packagist.org/packages/automattic/woocommerce).

And you can use the [`batch` endpoint for product tags](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#batch-update-product-tags) (`/wp-json/wc/v3/products/tags/batch`) to create/update/delete multiple (by default, up to 100) product tags at a time. Here's an example for **creating** multiple product tags:

```php
$data = [
    'create' => [
        [
            'name' => 'Round toe',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Flat',
        ],
    ],
];

print_r( $woocommerce->post( 'products/tags/batch', $data ) );
```

Comment: Working perfectly, thanks very much Sally!

Comment: Next step for me is to try create both new tag(s) and products via the api and assign the new tag to the new product at the same time.

Comment: Okay, good luck with that! :) ( and just a gentle reminder, if you got stuck, try asking on Stack Overflow first since WC questions here are off-topic.. :) )

Comment: Oh! Honestly thought WC questions fit better here than on Stack Overflow personally but thanks for the heads up.